# Filtering by minute with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok so I have a dataset/frame with pandas and I want to select one row per minute to get a more accurate view of the simulation. As the times in the dataframe are too close together.

[image: as seen in the picture under local time I have very many timestamps per minute]

```
req_columns = [4,5,6, 9]
df = pd.read_excel('Flt0052UV.xlsx', skiprows = range(1,33656), usecols= req_columns)
df = df[~df.Longitude.isnull()]
```

here is how I currently select the data any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resample()` on your datetime with `first()`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[i for i in range(3600)], index=pd.date_range(start='01/01/2022', periods=3600, freq='s'), columns=['data'])

df = df.resample('1min').first()
```

Output:

```
                     data
2022-01-01 00:00:00     0
2022-01-01 00:01:00    60
2022-01-01 00:02:00   120
2022-01-01 00:03:00   180
         ...          ...
```

Comment: Ok I see how your solution works but now I cannot convert my column to datetime I'm unsure of this error thanks so much